# Could be Borel summation applied for Riemann zeta function in the strip region?

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation, riemann-zeta, exponential-sum

In mathematics, [Borel summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_summation) is a summation method for divergent series,  It is particularly useful for summing divergent asymptotic series, and in some sense gives the best possible sum for such series , I want to know if it is possible to apply the one of methods of Borel summation for Riemann zeta function .then my question here is :

> > **Question:** Could be Borel summation applied for Riemann zeta function in the strip region ?

Comment: Try applying to $a_k(s) = (-1)^{k+1}k^{-s}$ the same method as [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1896694/showing-etas-lim-z-to-1-sum-n-1-infty-zn-n-s). It should converge to $\eta(s) = (1-2^{1-s}) \zeta(s)$ at least with the *Borel's integral summation method with analytic continuation*