# Regularizing the sum of integers with the aid of the Taylor expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, asymptotics, riemann-zeta, divergent-series

One way to understand how the sum of all factorials
$$
S_{\mathbb{N}!} = 1! + 2! + 3! + \ldots
$$
can be regularized comes from an observation that the function
$$
f(x) = \text{P.V.}\int \limits_0^\infty \dfrac{\operatorname{e}^{-t}}{1-t\,x} \operatorname{d}t
$$
is finite for $x>0$, while its Taylor expansion is
$$
f(x) = 0! + 1!x + 2!x^2 + 3!x^3 + \ldots
$$
So, we can assign $S_{\mathbb{N}!} = f(1)$.

I'm wondering if same can be done for the sum of all integers
$$
S_{\mathbb{N}} = 1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots
$$
Clearly, we cannot use the function $\dfrac{x}{(x-1)^2}$, since it is not defined at $x=1$. Still, I'm wondering if it's possible to come up with smth similar to the case of factorials.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2190762/could-be-borel-summation-applied-for-riemann-zeta-function-in-the-strip-region) is actually a closely related question.

Comment: Let $F(z) =  \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{1-tz}dt$ which is analytic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus [0,\infty)$ and $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{F^{(k)}(z)}{k!} = \int_0^\infty t^k e^{-t}dt = k!$. Then what ?

Comment: In physics we often encounter asymototic series with $a_k\propto k!$ (tunneling processes in QM and QFT). In these situations we 'regularize' the result by evaluating $F(z)$ instead of $\sum a_nz^n$ (which is divergent). We reconstruct $F(z)$ from the series using Borel summation or other more involved techniques. So my question is how to do same with a series whose coefficients grow linearly, not factorially.

Comment: So you interpret $F(z) = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{1-tz}dt, z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus [0,\infty)$ as a regularized version of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n! z^n$ ? With $a_n=n$ then $G(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ does converge for $|z| < 1$. Then what ?

Comment: The expansion of $F(z)$ is divergent for any $z>0$. The point of regularization is that it allows me to assign a finite value to the series $\sum n!z^n$ at the points where it diverges. I would like to do the same thing with the second series and evaluate it at $z=1$.

Comment: $G(z)= \frac{z}{(z-1)^2}$ has a double pole at $z=1$ $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{G(1+\epsilon)+G(1+i\epsilon)+G(1-\epsilon)+G(1-i\epsilon)}{4}=0$$ is finite. Note this is quite similar to what you do with $F(z)$ as $$\text{pv}.\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{1-tx}dt = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{F(x+i\epsilon)+F(x-i\epsilon)}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks!! This really helps.

Comment: I'm surprised though the answer is not $-1/12$, as given by other 'regularizations'.