# $\lim\limits_{s\to0^+}\sum_n\frac{\cos\left(\pi\frac{n}{m}\right)}{n^s}$ & $\lim\limits_{s\to0^+}\sum_n\frac{\sin\left(\pi\frac{n}{m}\right)}{n^s}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, trigonometric-series

> $(1).$ Show that: 
>   $$ \lim_{s\to0^+}\,\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos\left(\pi\frac{n}{m}\right)\frac{1}{n^s}\right]=\color{red}{-\frac{1}{2}} \quad\colon\space\forall\,m\in\mathbb{N}^{+}\tag{1} $$ 
>   $(2).$ Find a closed-form for: 
>   $$ \lim_{s\to0^+}\,\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin\left(\pi\frac{n}{m}\right)\frac{1}{n^s}\right]=\color{red}{\,\,\,\,?\,\,\,\,} \quad\colon\space\,\,\,\,m\in\mathbb{N}^{+}\tag{2} $$

Both series converge by Dirichlet's test for $\mathrm{Re}(s)>0$. 
  
 
I could not find a good reason way the first series shall converge to the same constant!! 
  
 
Thanks for you help.

Comment: The limit in $(2)$ equals $\dfrac12 \cot\left(\dfrac \pi{2m}\right)$.

Comment: @Tianlalu: Thanks, but how to show it (if it is the correct answer)?

Comment: If we can prove $\lim_{s\to0^+}\operatorname{Li}_s(z)= \operatorname{Li}_0(z)$, then the question is trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$f(z,s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n^s}$$ can be analytically continue to all complex $z$ except $z\in \mathbf R \bigwedge z\ge1$ and for complex $s$ in the disk $|s|<1$. So we need only to evaluate $f(z,s=0)$ for $|z|<1$. That is 
$$f(z,s=0)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z^n=\frac z{1-z},\, \forall |z|<1.$$ 
Analytically continue this fraction to $|z|=1\bigwedge z\ne 1$, we have $\forall\theta\in\mathbf R\bigwedge\theta\ne0$
$$\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}f(e^{i\theta},s)= \lim_{z\rightarrow e^{i\theta}\atop s\rightarrow 0} f(z,s)=\lim_{z\rightarrow e^{i\theta}} f(z,s=0)=\frac  {e^{i\theta}}{1- e^{i\theta}}=-\frac12+\frac i2\cot\frac \theta 2.$$
Separating out the real and imaginary parts of the above equation, we obtain the desired results.

Comment: ... can be analytically continue to the whole complex plane except at $z\in \mathbf R \bigwedge z\ge1 \bigwedge s=1$ No, consider $s=2$, it is not even meromorphic in the complex plane. And the imaginary part is missing a factor $\frac12$. Just to be rigorous, the general idea of your answer is correct.

Comment: @KemonoChen: You are right. Thank you. I have made the correction. I will add even more details later.

Comment: I wish if I can split the bounty, many thanks.

Comment: @HazemOrabi: Haha. No worries.

Answer (score 4):

Denote $\frac\pi m=x$, rewrite $$\lim_{s\to0^+}\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos\left(\pi\frac{n}{m}\right)\frac{1}{n^s}\right]=\lim_{s\to0^+}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{ixn}+e^{-ixn}}{2n^s}\\
=\lim_{s\to0^+}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{ixn}+e^{-ixn}}{2n^s}\\
=\lim_{s\to0^+}\frac12\left(\operatorname{Li}_s(e^{ix})+\operatorname{Li}_s(e^{-ix})\right)$$where $\operatorname{Li}_s(z)$ is the analytic continuation of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n^s}$ and is named polylogarithm function.
[Notice that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1896694/showing-etas-lim-z-to-1-sum-n-1-infty-zn-n-s) $\operatorname{Li}_s(z)$ is holomorphic in $s$ in a neighborhood of the origin whatever $z$ is, hence continuous in $s\in(0,\epsilon)$. We have
$$\lim_{s\to0^+}\frac12\left(\operatorname{Li}_s(e^{ix})+\operatorname{Li}_s(e^{-ix})\right)=\frac12\left(\operatorname{Li}_0(e^{ix})+\operatorname{Li}_0(e^{-ix})\right)=\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{e^{i x}}{1-e^{i x}}+\frac{e^{-i x}}{1-e^{-i x}}\right)=\frac12$$
Similarly, $$\lim_{s\to0^+}\,\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin\left(\pi\frac{n}{m}\right)\frac{1}{n^s}\right]=\frac1{2i}\left(\operatorname{Li}_0(e^{ix})-\operatorname{Li}_0(e^{-ix})\right)=\frac{1}{2} i \left(\frac{e^{-i x}}{1-e^{-i x}}-\frac{e^{i x}}{1-e^{i x}}\right)=\frac12\cot\frac x2$$
**Evaluation of $\operatorname{Li}_0(z)$**
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n^0}=z\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n=\frac{z}{1-z}(|z|<1)$$
Since $\operatorname{Li}_0(z)$ is the analytic continuation of it, $\operatorname{Li}_0(z)=\frac{z}{1-z}$.

Comment: According to this development, $m$ need not be restricted to the natural numbers.

Comment: It is slightly surreal to see a solution jumping to fine properties of polylogarithms to "help" an OP whose background is obviously lacking these.